# Web form javascript image refresh with interval

Tags: javascript, image, webforms

Please help me to refresh periodically an image in a web form (asp.net).
Here is my code. The image is not refreshing. Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
                var obj = document.getElementById("<%=Image1.ClientID%>");
                var src = obj.src;
                var pos = src.indexOf("?");
                if (pos >= 0) {
                    scr = src.substr(0, pos);
                }
                var date = new Date();
                obj.src = src + '?v=' + date.getTime();
                return true;
            }, 10000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/sOverview.png" />    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the code behind:

```vb
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Image1.ImageUrl = Image1.ImageUrl + "?" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem? Does the ASP.NET fail to generate the JS you expect it to generate or does the JS not behave as you expect? Either way, you should show us the generated code rather than just the server side code.

Comment: What does the JavaScript console say? Does the code run without errors?

Comment: There are no errors on page but the image is not refreshed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script element gets its script from *either* the text node inside it, or the URL of the `src` attribute.  Not both.

If you want to load two scripts (one from a URL and on in the text node) then you need *two* script elements.

Comment: Could you show me how to change the code in order to be correct?

Comment: You just use two `script` elements. One with a `src` attribute that points to jQuery. One with the other script inside it.

Comment: I am afraid that I do not understand. Could you please show me how?

Comment: `<script src="..."></script><script>...</script>`.

Comment: I change the code to:<script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"> but I have an error "element script is missing required atribute "type"